# CommunicationException is lifted, even in a try/catch block

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-phone-7

I'm currently developping an application for WP7 that needs to make calls to a WCF Service Application. I tested the service with a small WPF application and everything went just fine. But now that I call it from my WP7 app, I systematically get the following exception :

```
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in
System.ServiceModel.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException was unhandled by user code
    HResult=-2146233087
    Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
    Source=System.ServiceModel
    InnerException: System.Net.WebException
        HResult=-2146233079
        Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
        Source=System.Windows
        InnerException: System.Net.WebException
             HResult=-2146233079
             Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
             Source=System.Windows
             InnerException:
```

The exception keeps getting lifted despite the fact I make my service call within a try/catch block like this (in MyProjectPath.Model.User.cs) :

```
public Task<User> Load(string logon, string pwHash)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<User> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<User>();

    client.GetUserByCredsCompleted += ((s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error == null) tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
            else
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendLine("Error encountered while getting data :");
                sb.AppendLine(e.Error.Message);

                MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
            }
        });
    try
    {
        client.GetUserByCredsAsync(logon, pwHash);
    }
    catch (System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

And when executed, the exception occurs here (in System.ServiceModel.ni.dll) :

```
public MyProjectPath.ServiceReference.User EndGetUserByCreds(System.IAsyncResult result) {
    object[] _args = new object[0];
        // Exception gets lifted by the following line :
    MyProjectPath.ServiceReference.User _result = ((MyProjectPath.ServiceReference.User)(base.EndInvoke("GetUserByCreds", _args, result)));
    return _result;
}
```

Did anyone already encountered this problem and solved it ? I must admit I'm pretty clueless here...

Answer (score 0):

You're calling an asynchronous API. Although you're wrapping that call in a try/catch block, that call will presumably be starting up a new thread or queueing a request for another existing thread to pick up. Either way, your try/catch is only protecting you against exceptions thrown on the thread which makes the call, and there aren't any. The (start of) your asynchronous call succeeds just fine, so the catch block never comes into effect, and then control is passed to the other thread and this is where the exception is thrown.

You can't protect against exceptions in EndGetUserByCreds by wrapping your call to GetUserByCredsAsync in a try/catch. The two methods are executing at different times different threads. You need to modify EndGetUserByCreds so that it catches exceptions and deals with them appropriately, rather than letting them crash the thread.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but do you have any idea on why the service can't find the server while the WCF Test Client and my WPF test app can access the data without any problem ?

Also, I can't edit the file where the exception is lifted (or just don't know how), as it is inside a dll that's been generated when I added the service reference.

Comment: Ok, I just figured out this snippet could actually be found in Reference.cs and I added the necessary try/catch block. Now the app is stable... But still not working :-/